# How can i wrap bootstrap cols with div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, wrapper, responsive

I want to wrap my col-*-5 with div.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5"> content1 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5"> content2 </div>
   </div>
 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
</div>
```

My wrapper has width as body and height = 1. I tried to add `overflow: hidden;` In this case div wrapps my cols-5 but last col-1 is moving to the next line (wrapper does not end after second col-5, it goes to the end of page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper should have bootstrap width class, perhaps `col-xs-10`. Then the inners `xs-6` etc?

```css
.col-xs-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col1</div>
  <div class="wrapper col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">content1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">content2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col1</div>
</div>
```